# React epub using only Readium.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, implementation, epub, epub.js

In the past, I used [Epub.js](http://epubjs.org/documentation/0.3/) for my project. However, the whole epub content must be available to load the book. On researching, I found a cool library called [Readium.js](https://github.com/readium/readium-js). Don't know how to integrate it with react.js.

Can someone help me with this!!!